# AppleScript to facilitate Print to PDF in Safari Browser

Tags: pdf, safari, applescript

I wrote an AppleScript whose purpose is to trigger Safari's "print to pdf" functionality. The script fails at line 14 when attempting to select the "Save as PDF" from the menu button "PDF"

```
-- Found some reusable code snippets here
--https://www.macscripter.net/t/gui-scripting-of-print-dialog/45378/3
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1
            delay 1
        end repeat
        click menu button "PDF" of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
            delay 1
        end repeat
        click menu item "Save as PDF" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
    end tell
end tell
```

Any ideas on how to select menu items from the "PDF" menu button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delay 1
perform action "AXShowMenu" of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
perform action "AXPress" of menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu "PDF" of menu button "PDF" of sheet 1 of window 1
```

Three things… I added a delay here because sometimes it takes a moment for the sheet to populate. It's building a preview which isn't instantaneous, especially for large or complex pages. Second, `Save as PDF…` requires that the ellipsis be included. Third, you have to run out the string of `of` with the menu items. This means including `of sheet 1 of window 1`.

Finally, you can use `click` but I used the associated `action` for each item, which I find more reliable (as they're less ambiguous).